# Unity3d 5 WavePro Dynamic MeshCollider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im using Water4Advance to simulate an ocean waves in Unity3d 5.0.
I have my plane displaced in Runtime with Gerstner Displace.
I see how the mesh is deformed and i add a MeshCollider to it and i like to refresh this collider mesh in runtime.
I was working this on Unity 4.6 with this script:

```
MeshCollider collider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
collider.sharedMesh = null;
collider.sharedMesh = mesh;
```

But now i only got the flat original plane prefab.
[image]

How can i update this MeshCollider with the displaced mesh?

Comment: When or how often do you assign the mesh to the collider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mesh myMesh = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
DestroyImmediate(this.GetComponent<MeshCollider>());
var collider = this.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
collider.sharedMesh = myMesh;
```

From here:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/446910/changing-mesh-collider-at-run-time.html

Comment: Not work for me. I try this but i not get the Water4 modified mesh on collider.

Comment: Hmm--could you post a small sample Unity sample project demonstrating this?

Comment: The script is attached in Tile1

Comment: Hmm, so I think the problem here is that the vertex displacment for the wave is being done on the GPU in a shader--so the CPU side doesn't have access to it.  I don't have a good solution at this point.  There is some discussion here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/971281/mesh-collision-on-displacement-shader.html  Even if possible, I think performance may be a real issue here.

Comment: I think the only solution here is to rewrite the shader deformation code in a script and execute it on an identical mesh that you used for the collider.  Not at all ideal.  :-(  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/175600/gpu-generated-mesh.html