# How to animate the results in Unity 5?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The unity has a `SkinnedMeshRenderer` object, which is a skinned mesh model controlled by `poseBlendValues` and `shapeBlendValues`. Now I have a program that can generate sequential `poseBlendValues` and `shapeBlendValues`. I build a model with Unity5, and write a script to the model. In the script, I set the `SkinnedMeshRenderer` object via `SetBlendShapeWeight` with my computed values. However, the model does not deform as expected. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

This is a piece of my code which is the Start function, the script will receive the parameters from the server via `fetchAllParms` and then set the params for the model with `SetBlendShapeValues`. And `resetShapeParms()` and `resetPoseParms()` just clear the array `_shapeParms` and `_poseParms` to zeros. `setShapeBlendValues()` and `setPoseBlendValues()` just fill `_shapeParms` and `_poseParms` with the fetched values. When I click `Play`, I can see the BlendShape parameters are changed in the Inspector View, but the model does dot deform as expected.

```
void Start()
{
    client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    _shapeParms = new float[_numShapeParms];
    _camParms = new float[_numCamParms];
    _poseParms = new float[_numPoseParms];

    resetShapeParms();
    resetPoseParms();
    fetchAllParms();
    setShapeBlendValues();

    setPoseBlendValues();


}
```

Comment: check if this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256007/unity3d-5-wavepro-dynamic-meshcollider

Comment: No. My problem is that when I change the shapeblendvalues for the skinned mesh renderer in the script, the mesh does not change correspondingly.